# How to remove Buzzdock ads from Google search results?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8.1, malware, anti-malware

[image]

Everytime I search for something on Google, I get this block of Buzzdock ads, as you can see on the screenshot. I am trying to get rid of this.

I've already unistalled a program called "Buzzdock 2" and run a myriad of antispyware and antimalware (such as Malwarebytes, AdMalware, HitmanPro etc) without success.

I've also tried disabling all Chrome extensions except for Adblock, but to no avail.

I'm using Windows 8.1 and my version of Google Chrome is `Version 40.0.2214.111 m`.

I don't get these ads on Internet Explorer.

How can I get rid of them on Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the Chrome profile?

Comment: No I haven't. But I'd rather avoid it.I don't know what  the consequences is and I don't wanna loose my markers.

Comment: Use this to export your bookmarks: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=pt-PT , then delete the profile.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your default search provider might have been changed.  You can change that by going into Chrome's settings and changing the default search provider.

If that doesn't stick (that is, it's changed back after you try to fix it, then you may have something installed that's trying to keep it that way.  There are a few different articles on the 'net that talk about what might need to be removed.  I found [this one](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-buzzdock-ads/) by searching for "buzzwords remove chrome" (other searches may be more effective.

Comment: You can see in the URL that he's still at google.pl (which is an official google domain, its nameservers point to ns1/ns2.google.com). So unless google.com has been replaced with an iframe or something (which I doubt) it's not this.

Comment: @Chipperyman irrelevant, but it's google.pt - Google Portugal. :)

Comment: My bad! It's too late to edit unfortunately.

Comment: It's not the URL I'm looking at.  It's the "ads provided by" portion.  That's what, to me, suggests that the search provider has been hijacked.  You may be right, though, it may not be that...but given the number of hits on the keywords I mentioned, it's worth a look.

Comment: I only have Google as default search provider.

Answer (score 0):

As I said [on a similar thread](https://superuser.com/a/874757/33758), running the [free version of MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) (yes, I saw that OP has already tried it) and then [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) usually remove all browser malware-caused redirections and inserted ads. There are many fake antivirus programs that only make things worse, but [AdwCleaner is trusted by major forums](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) and works great in my personal experience.

Avoid installing suspicious programs and extensions in the future, and make sure to untick all "optional offers" checkboxes when you install something. You may want to keep [Unchecky](http://unchecky.com/) running on your computer.

Comment: If you know I've tried this, how exactly does this answer my question?

Comment: @BrunoMiguelGonçalves I know you've tried MalwareBytes, but you didn't mention the second program, which is the focus of my answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I already tried the Adw Cleaner. Sorry.